# Writing dates separately in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML document with the Javascript externally linked.

I need to create three seperate variables and call The Day, The Month, And the Year.

I don’t understand at all. I have tried code from we3 schools and it just doesn’t make sense to me.

Can someone please show me how to make these different items(day, month, year) display? I am losing my mind.

I would love if someone could show me to code and what it means because I have been reading different code all day but it’s like reading another language and I don’t understand.

TYIA

Here is my code. I have no idea what I'm doing so I'm sure it's a mess!

```
var myDate = new Date();
console.log(myDate);


function showDate(){
    var mn = date.getMonth();
    var d = date.getDay();
    var y = date.getCurrentYear();

    var date = mn + d + y session;
    document.getElementById("'Month', 'Day', 'Year'")

}
```

Comment: Show what code you’ve tried, so we know where you got hung up.

Comment: Need to see your code, `new Date();` for example will get the date

Answer (score 2):

What I suspect you want is readable months, dates, ect. JavaScript doesn't support that out of the box. So you'll need to create arrays to hold those values so you can present something readable to the user; however, please read on to my MomentJS example at the end.

```js
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]


function showDate(){
  var fullDate = new Date();    
  var d = fullDate.getDay();
  var m = fullDate.getMonth();
  var y = fullDate.getFullYear();

  var date = `${months[m]} ${d}, ${y}`;
  document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date;

}

showDate();
```

```html
<div id="date"><div>
```

Dates have already been figured out by [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/), and you really should just use that

```js
function showDate() {
  var date = moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY');
  document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date;
}

showDate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="date"></div>
```

#### Code feedback on your original code

1. In your code you use `document.getElementById("'Month', 'Day', 'Year'")`. you can only reference one id per `getElementById`, so this won't work.
2. Also, the above is just a reference to an element on the page (aka, the DOM). You need to assign a value to it using `.innerHTML`
3. You have the variable `session` randomly in your function
4. You'll have to call your function to make that code run. i.e., `showDate()`

Comment: This worked. THank you SO MUCH!!!! 

I have been trying to figure this out for HOURS. I understand HTML and CSS Coding but I'm just learning JS now and Idon't understand it in the slightest. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: BTW @newgirl456, since my solution solved your problem, please do accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is preemptive, because you didn’t post code showing what you’re actually dealing with, but here is how to get the values from JS:

```
var now = new Date()

var day = now.getDay()
var year = now.getFullYear()

var month = now.getMonth() // in November, this will return the number 10
```

Check out MDN for the deets: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

With your code now, I will make these changes:

```
function showDate() {
  document.getElementById('idOfYourElement').innerHTML = new Date().getDate() // cheating a little
}
```

I would strongly recommend buying some courses on Udemy (or wherever) and taking your time with them. This stuff takes time and effort, but if you go through the hard work, you will build a solid framework in your mind for learning concepts like this at a rapid pace.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. I'm sorry but I don't understand why it doesn't work for me!! I Removed my previous code and it didn't display and so I tried starting a new document to see and the date still didn't display. I'm not sure what I"m doing wrong! :(

Answer (score 0):

OK I am also going to answer your question without code. So to get the date you have to first declare varible to get that date.

```
var fullDate = new Date();    
var theDay = fullDate.getDay();
var theMonth = fullDate.getMonth();
var theYear = fullDate.getFullYear();

console.log(theDay+" "+theMonth+" "+theYear);
```

In my case I called it fullDate to be clear that it gets a new instance of the date. Then you use the dot connector to get what ever else you need from that date. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

I hope this helps.

Edit: you added information chnage

```
 var mn = date.getMonth();
    var d = date.getDay();
    var y = date.getCurrentYear();
```

You have used `date.` why? use `myDate` which you created earlier.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. I'm sorry but I don't understand why it doesn't work for me!! I Removed my previous code and it didn't display and so I tried starting a new document to see and the date still didn't display. I'm not sure what I"m doing wrong! :(

Comment: OK I think I get what you are doing. You are adding things together. Give me a moment I will produce a new answer and explain what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code

```
var myDate = new Date();
console.log(myDate);


function showDate(){
    var mn = myDate.getMonth();
    var d = myDate.getDay();
    var y = myDate.getFullYear();

    var date = mn+" "+d+" "+y;
    console.log(date);

}
```

So to print or display the date, you will need to force the space in between. Before you had the date value, in this case 11 and 30 and 2018 then because all you had was a  plus sign js looks at those values and recognize them as integers. Thus it was simply adding them together.

By adding `+" "+` to the equation it stops js from doing math and rather it treats the whole thing as a string and will print off the values as such in the order you have told it to do so.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel like an idiot but the date is still not displaying when I input this into the code. 

The code that I'm trying to get it to work with already had a working clock. SO i tried to input it into a new document just to see and it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

OK, there are a couple of bugs in the code that you have posted. Here is the breakdown of your code:

```
var myDate = new Date();
console.log(myDate);
```

**new Date()** creates a Date object with the built-in Date function. You set the variable **myDate** to have the value of the just created date object. Then **console.log(myDate)** logs the variable to the console. If you open(Ctrl + Shift + I) the console, and reload the web page, you will see the value of myDate written to the console.No errors on this part. Now to the other part:

```
function showDate(){
    var mn = date.getMonth();
    var d = date.getDay();
    var y = date.getCurrentYear();

    var date = mn + d + y session;
    document.getElementById("'Month', 'Day', 'Year'")

}
```

This is where the errors are. The variable "date" in *date.getMonth()*, *date.getDay()* and
*date.getCurrentYear* is *NOT* defined. Hence it is not a Date object and so cannot use the methods *getMonth()* and *getDay()*. You should instead use **myDate** which you have previously defined as a Date object e.g. **myDate.getDay()**. Also *getCurrentYear()* is not a valid method, you should instead use *getYear()* or *getFullYear()* to return the current year e.g. **myDate.getYear()**. Another bug here is that *"session"* stands on its own, thus making no sense.

Finally, *document.getElementById(htmlElementId)* takes only a single argument. This argument is the value of the *id* attribute of an html element. For example suppose a paragraph element of an html document is defined as:

```
<p id="paraID">This is a paragraph</p>
```

To access this paragraph element, you would have to pass the value of the *id* attribute ***paraID*** as an argument to *getElementById()* e.g.

```
var para = document.getElementById(paraID);
```

You probably want the date to be displayed on the web page. Putting together these fixes, one possible error free version of your code could be:

```
var myDate = new Date();
console.log(myDate);


function showDate(){
    var mn = myDate.getMonth();
    var d = myDate.getDay();
    var y = myDate.getYear();

    var date = mn + "/" + d + "/" + y;
    var element = document.getElementById(htmlElementId);// htmlElementId is id value
    element.innerHTML = date;

}
showDate();
```